# git merge going wrong?

Tags: git, git-merge

**ORIGINAL:**

```
  "<tasks>"
+ " <exec command="ls">"
+ "  <runif status="failed" />"
+ " </exec>"
+ " <exec command="ls">"
+ "  <runif status="failed" />"
+ " </exec>"
+ "</tasks>";
```

**MODIFICATION_1:**

```
  "<tasks>"
+ " <exec command="ls">"
+ "  <runif status="failed" />"
+ " </exec>"
+ "</tasks>";
```

**MODIFICATION_2:**

```
 "<tasks>"
+ " <exec command="ls">"
+ "  <runif status="passed" />"
+ " </exec>"
+ " <exec command="ls">"
+ "  <runif status="failed" />"
+ " </exec>"
+ "</tasks>";
```

**RESULT:**

```
  "<tasks>"
+ " <exec command="ls">"
+ "  <runif status="passed" />"
+ " </exec>"
+ "</tasks>";
```

**EXPECTED_RESULT:**

```
 "<tasks>"
+ " <exec command="ls">"
+ "  <runif status="failed" />"
+ " </exec>"
+ "</tasks>";
```

The original content in file is **ORIGINAL**.

Someone cut a branch at this point and edited **ORIGINAL** to **MODIFICATION_2**. (change first `<exec>` node from `failed` to `passed`)

While on `master` someone changed **ORIGINAL** to **MODIFICATION_1**. (delete of first `<exec>` node)

When merging the branch into master the changes are like **RESULT** (the change in the branch is applied to the second `<exec>` node instead of first which is deleted!) instead of producing the **EXPECTED_RESULT** or resulting in a merge conflict!

Is this expected behavior? Can someone explain why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is, that both `<exec>` nodes are identical in **ORIGINAL**. Hence the deletion by **MODIFICATION_1** is ambiguous (it could either be the first or the second instance) and the merging algorithm actually manages to apply both changes without any overlap, thus not resulting in a merge conflict.

Comment: Hm, that sounds like it applies the patches sequentially, rather than using a 3-way merge?